# max-width is not working for mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make a responsive layout using `@media`. I'm testing it out via chrome dev tools, and the mobile screen size isn't working **only** when testing for mobile on chrome, by clicking <kbd>f12</kbd> (to open dev tools in chrome) then hit <kbd>ctr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>M</kbd> .

When you resize, `@media (max-width: 480px)` never gets toggled. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

#### Codepen

```css
/* Width is less than x*/

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
/* Width is greater than x*/

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  body {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
/* Width is greater than x*/

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    background-color: orange;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me, maybe you expect first query to be applied at 480px? Just increase min-width to 481px and you good to go.

```css
/* Width is equals or less than x*/

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
/* Width is equals or greater than x*/

@media (min-width: 481px) {
  body {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
/* Width is equals or greater than x*/

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  body {
    background-color: orange;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Have you included the meta viewport tag in your index.html?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```